# "Object to" phrasal verb or not

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, transitivity, active-voice

**He objected to the proposal.**

The above is a sentence to change into passive voice from a grammar book. The answer was also given.

According to the Oxford dictionary, **object** is given as intransitive in the given structure and **object to** is not given as a phrasal verb.

Is it possible to change into passive voice? If yes, how?

Comment: M-W says it is also a transitive verb!

Comment: Obect to + something..... Here it is intransitive.         Object + that clause..... Here it is transitive. The discussing point is about case 1

Comment: Some verbs license special prepositions, so, I suppose that to is just a preposition there. Like, he pointed at the floor. Or perhaps adverbial prepositional phrase!

Comment: The verb "object" is always intransitive. _That_ clauses are not objects.

Comment: If so, is PV possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object to" can be put into the passive voice as follows:

> The proposal was objected to.

or

> The proposal was objected to by him.

FYI, the use of passive voice in contexts like this is as ugly as sin.

Comment: Can "pray to", "suffer from" be considered as transitive phrasal verbs? Any tip to identify a transitive phrasal verb...?